# Can you combine multiple CI builds prior to a CD pipeline being triggered in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have 2 CI builds, one for the Database and one for Dotnet. These are triggered when a commit is made to the master branch for their corresponding directories, i.e. /database or /dotnet.

Off the back of the CI builds, a CD pipeline is triggered to actually deploy the new resources.

The problem I'm having is, if I merge a PR into master that has changes to both `/database` and `/dotnet`, 2 CI builds are triggered (correct) but then I also get 2 CD deployments (incorrect!). I'm trying to figure out a way that it will wait for both CI builds as they were in the same commit, and then trigger the CD pipeline.

Does anyone know if that's possible?

Below are the example files of a slimmed down code.

**File structure:**

```
├── CI-Database.yml
├── CI-Dotnet.yml
├── CD-Pipeline.yml
├── database
│   └── adatabasefile.sql
├── deploy-env.yml
└── dotnet
    └── adotnetfile.cs
```

**CI-Database.yml**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - database

name: $(Build.DefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)_$(SourceBranchName)

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - script: echo 'Hello from database'

  - publish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/database'
    artifact: 'the-database'
```

**CI-Dotnet.yml**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - dotnet

name: $(Build.DefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)_$(SourceBranchName)

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - script: echo 'Hello from dotnet pipeline'

  - publish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dotnet'
    artifact: 'the-dotnet'
```

**CD-Pipeline.yml**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - infrastructure

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: databasepipeline
    source: CI-Database
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - main
  - pipeline: dotnetpipeline
    source: CI-Dotnet
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - main

stages:
- stage: DeployDEV
  displayName: 'DEV Deploy'
  jobs:
    - job: 
      steps: 
        - pwsh: Write-Host "Deploy the consumed CI resources here"
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Multiple resource triggers are an *or* not an *and*. That is the implemented behavior there's no way to change it. The only thing you can change is your process.

In general, there's no reason to have separate pipelines for build versus deployment. You can break a single pipeline up into multiple jobs with `dependsOn` relationships and conditional stages.

Comment: Putting them into one pipeline would result in unnecessary building of other CI pipelines, given that it may only be the dotnet project that had changes..

Comment: I tend to agree with David. It's not best to have a single solution build my 7 projects every time when all I do is modify one of them. We're going to try out a solution that the CI's will check to ensure they're the last one done and then tag the final CI. That tag we'll use as a pipeline trigger to ensure the CD only fires when all are complete. The CD will contain all Deployments with conditions to ensure they only deploy when new artifacts have been released.